# how i can get all option from select with javascript / jQuery and save data in object

Tags: javascript

```
<select id='listOfOptions' >
    <option sid='15' value='test'>test</option>
    <option sid='15' value='test2'>test2</option>
    <option sid='16' value='plah'>plah</option>
    <option sid='16' value='plah2'>plah2</option>
</select>
```

I need to fetch all the data from select> option>
to a var in the following form

```
object = {
   '15':('test','test2'),
   '16':('plah','plah2')
}
```

Comment: That format is invalid. I assume you want [] and not () to surround the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Array.reduce`.

Logic

- Select the options of the `select` tag by picking the select from DOM. I used `document.getElementById`. You could make use of `document.querySelector` or any other selecter mechanism.
- This will retrn a [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection). You can convert this to array using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- Use `Array.reduce` to gruop this based on your `sid`
- I have also made use of Object destructuring to access sid attribute answell as the option value.

```js
// Select the list options in the select
const options = document.getElementById('listOfOptions').options;

// Execute Array.reduce
const group = Array.from(options).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // Destructuring the curr object to access the option value and sid value
  const { value, attributes: { sid: { value: sidValue } } } = curr;
  acc[sidValue] ? acc[sidValue].push(value) : acc[sidValue] = [value];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(group)
```

```html
<select id='listOfOptions' >
  <option sid='15' value='test'>test</option>
  <option sid='15' value='test2'>test2</option>
  <option sid='16' value='plah'>plah</option>
  <option sid='16' value='plah2'>plah2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Spoonfeeding ready-made answers with little explanation is less helpful than a more thoroughly explained answer, especially for new contributors, and especially for these kinds of easier, softball questions.

Comment: I make these kinds of comments on all answers like the original revision. That is, answers with code and little explanation. If anything, I'm more likely to comment the higher the reputation, because people with higher rep should know better that more explanation is better.

Comment: But I have never seen such things for higher reputed users. if you are doing its really nice. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a data-attribute for the `sid`, and then iterate over the options and create a new object with `forEach`.

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('#listOfOptions option');

const obj = {};

options.forEach(el => {

  // Grab the sid and value from the option element
  const { dataset: { sid }, value } = el;

  // If `sid` is not a key on the object
  // create it, and set the value to an empty array
  if (!obj[sid]) obj[sid] = [];

  // Push the value to the array
  obj[sid].push(value);

});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<select id="listOfOptions">
  <option data-sid="15" value="test">test</option>
  <option data-sid="15" value="test2">test2</option>
  <option data-sid="16" value="plah">plah</option>
  <option data-sid="16" value="plah2">plah2</option>
</select>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)